# How to fix YouTube-dl Invalid parameters. on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, youtube-dl

When I try to download a song with `youtube-dl.rb` gem it works locally, but when I do it on Heroku it says this:

```
Terrapin::ExitStatusError - Command '/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/youtube-dl.rb-0.3.1.2016.09.11.1/vendor/bin/youtube-dl --no-color --no-progress --print-json "ytsearch:notion hooked"' returned 1. Expected 0
```

It also says something about `cocaine` being deprecated like this:

```
DEPRECATION: The cocaine gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to terrapin. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/terrapin/ for further instructions.
```

This is my  code that is running this gem:

```rb
song_list.each { |song|
        # formatted_command = 'youtube-dl -o "' + __dir__.to_s + '/' + temp_dir_name + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 "ytsearch:' + song + '"'
        # system formatted_command
        options = {
            audio_format: :mp3,
            extract_audio: true,
            output: "#{__dir__.to_s}/#{temp_dir_name}/%(title)s.%(ext)s",
        }
        YoutubeDL.download "ytsearch:#{song}", options
    }
```

I commented two lines above that were downloading songs with the CLI tool, that worked as well, but I can't download that tool on a Heroku machine, so I have to use this Ruby wrapper.

Comment: Open up console with `heroku run bash` and try to run your command there, maybe you'll see a more specific error. Also, it is possible to embed the actual library in your codebase, you would probably need the python buildpack in addition to ruby

Comment: Do you know if I could download youtube-dl itself somehow on Heroku machine so I dont have to use this Ruby wrapper?

Comment: I made some instructions to run youtube-dl on your server. If it doesn't work, just let me know and I will delete the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll test the answer later today and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some instructions to running `youtube-dl` on your Heroku server:

1. create a `requirements.txt` file in the root of your repo, with content:

```
youtube-dl
```

2. Run the following three commands to set up Python buildpack *as well as* Ruby buildpack, making sure Ruby is the *primary* buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
```

Commit and deploy, test by opening `heroku run bash` and running `youtube-dl`. If it works here, you can also call it from Ruby.

Comment: That was perfect. So like this, I can install any command-line tool that is available through pip?

Comment: @crodev I'm really glad that worked. And yeah, any pip library.

Comment: @crodev keep in mine that youtube-dl does require frequent updates. I'm pretty sure it will update the version whe you redeploy, not 100% sure on that, though. I would do a search on how to update deps on heroku.

Comment: I know this is off topic with the question but, do you know if I can add some kind of proxy to Heroku machine because youtube-dl is blocking my IP because of too many requests(btw I made like 1 request)

Comment: @crodev sorry, can't help you out with that one. By the way, it's not youtube-dl blocking your IP, it's youtube.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the help anyway! I 'll try to figure it out.